# Codeigniter INNER JOIN with multiple ON

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Please can anyone help me to convert the following sql query into codeigniter database query

```
SELECT *
  FROM quotation q
  JOIN quotationdetail d
    ON d.customer = q.customer
   AND q.quoteid = d.quoteid
 WHERE q.quoteid = 1
   AND q.customer = 'john'
```

Comment: What is the codeigniter code equivalent for `INNER JOIN` with only one `ON`?

Comment: $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('quotation');
        $this->db->join('quotationdetail', 'quotationdetail.customer = quotation.customer', 'inner');
        $this->db->where('quotation.quoteid','1');
        $this->db->where('quotation.customer','john');
        $query = $this->db->get();

Comment: Note that you're returning two columns called customer and two columns called quoteid. This is rarely useful. Never use `SELECT *`. Instead, always name and qualify only the columns you actually want returned.